# MVC Ajax Javascript OnComplete parameter function 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem where the javascript OnComplete function's event parameter does not have get_response() defined.

My view:

```
<div id="result"></div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Security", null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "result",
            OnBegin = "OnAjaxBegin",
            OnComplete = "OnAjaxComplete",
            OnFailure = "OnAjaxFailure"
        }))
    {
    ...
    }
</div>
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(HomeViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        // return PartialView();
        return Json(new { redirectTo = "/Admin" });
    }

    return View();
}
```

The javascript:

```
function OnAjaxComplete(sender) {
    var response = sender.get_response();  // <-- get_response is 'undefined'
    // ...
}
```

So there is no get_response() function on the sender paramater.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `HttpMethod = "Post"` in ur ajaxrequest and if u want to send some data to `OnAjaxComplete` function do it on `OnSuccess`  as :-

```
new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "result",
        OnBegin = "OnAjaxBegin",
        OnSuccess = "OnAjaxComplete(data)",
        OnFailure = "OnAjaxFailure",
        HttpMethod = "Post",
    }

function OnAjaxComplete(data) {
var response = data.redirectTo;    <--- //redirectTo which is returned from JSON  
// ...
}
```